# Declaring array in typescript and typeof is an object

Tags: javascript, typescript

So, I'm trying to make an app using ionic, which uses typescript as language.

I'm declaring an array, like this:

```
products = new Array();
```

It's an array, right?

But why when I console.log(typeof this.products), I get "object"

I'd like it to be an array, what can I do?

Comment: [`typeof` operator's possible values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#Description).

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`typeof []` is `object` as array is not a [type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#Description) in Javascript.

to check if your variable is an array you can us [`.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

```js
var arr1 = Array.isArray([1, 2, 3]);  
var arr2 = Array.isArray({foo: 123}); 

console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```

Or you can also use [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

```js
var arr1 = [1,2,3];
if(typeof arr1 === "object" && arr1 instanceof Array){
  console.log("It is an array");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped alot. But could I ask you one more thing? If I declare this object array (products: new Array()), is not the same as declaring an array like this (products: string[];), right? The object has some methods, like 'push'. What I need is to push something to this array dynamically, but I also need the type to be an array because I'm inserting it as data to a chartJs. So, basically, how can I transform this Array object to a simple array[] ? Thank you. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thats okay, but I would ask you to start a new question with description related to your current doubt. Question posted here helps a lot of people and hitting multiple doubts makes the question and answers hard to understand. Please close this one by marking it correct if it solves your problem and start a new thread. We will help you there..